# Mapping into differnet types with Automapper

Tags: automapper

There are two classes in my Model:

```
public class Operation
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Calculation Details { get; set; }
}

public class Calculation
{
    public long Value { get; set; }
    public List<decimal> Points { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping into this DTO:

```
public class OperationDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CalculationDto Details { get; set; }
}

public class CalculationDto
{
    public long Value { get; set; }
}

public class CalculationDetailedDto: CalculationDto
{
    public List<decimal> Points { get; set; }
}
```

And sometimes the Client can request detailed information about the calculation. For example, depending of the command-line options:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Operation, OperationDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Calculation, CalculationDto>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<Calculation, CalculationDetailedDto>();

        var operation = new Operation
                        {
                            Name = "Very complicated opertion.",
                            Details =
                                new Calculation
                                {
                                    Value = 1002,
                                    Points = new List<decimal> {1.2m, 2.4m, 3.7m}
                                }
                        };

        var operationDto = Mapper.Map<OperationDto>(operation);

        Debug.WriteLine("Operation name: '{0}' value: '{1}'", operationDto.Name, operationDto.Details.Value);

        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Details:");
            foreach (var point in ((CalculationDetailedDto) operationDto.Details).Points)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0}", point);
            }
        }
    }
```

How do i tell Automapper at runtime map the calculation into CalculationDetailedDto?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another OperationDto that uses the detailed calculationDto, and create a map from Operation to OperationDetailedDto:

```
public class OperationDetailedDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public CalculationDetailedDto Details { get; set; }
}  


Mapper.CreateMap<Operation, OperationDetailedDto>();


if (detailed) operationDto = Mapper.Map<Operation, OperationDto>(operation);
else operationDto = Mapper.Map<Operation, OperationDetailedDto(operation);
```

Comment: But I mapping operationDto not Calculation. 

<code>var operationDto = Mapper.Map<OperationDto>(operation);

Comment: Allright, I missed that. Concept is the same, I edited the answer to show.

Comment: thank you! You solution is good, but i used my own. 
I re-map calculation after checking command line argument.

`codeoperationDto.Details=Mapper.Map<CalculationDetailedDto>(operation.Details);`

P.S. Sorry i did not have enought reputation to vote for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not fit solution proposed @fiskeboss can use the following.

You can re-map Calculation to CalculationDetailedDto after checking the command line arguments.

```
        if (args.Length > 0)
        {
            operationDto.Details = Mapper.Map<CalculationDetailedDto>(operation.Details);
            Debug.WriteLine("Details:");
            foreach (var point in ((CalculationDetailedDto) operationDto.Details).Points)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("{0}", point);
            }
        }
```